# Communication between app make by Android Sdk and Unity

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, unity-game-engine, communication

I'm a newbie on Unity. I need to make some communication between an app made by Android Sdk with an app made by Unity. Can I send a custom broadcast between them? How can I register a broadcast receiver on Unity? Or is there any way to communicate between an app made by unity and android sdk.